# Servlet 3.0 MVC frameworks

Tags: java, servlets, frameworks

With the adoption of servlet3.0 it's appeared many articles on new features and bla bla, but really, is there any solid MVC framework which is targeted for the new specification ?

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2.1 uses some Servlet 3.0 specific features (and is hence not compatible with Servlet 2.5 anymore).

Other MVC frameworks seem to not be Servlet 3.0 targeted yet.